# java decrypt by X509 public key

Tags: java, encryption, digital-signature

As I am trying to encrypt the text to PKCS8 private key and decrypt by X509 public key.

```
      public static String decryptByPublicKey(String data, String keyHash) {
            final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
            final int MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK = 128;

            try {

                byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyHash);

                X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
                KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
                Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int offSet = 0;
                byte[] cache;
                byte[] buffer =data.getBytes();
                int inputLen = buffer.length;
                int i = 0;

                while (inputLen - offSet > 0) {
                    if (inputLen - offSet > MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK) {
                        cache = cipher.doFinal(buffer, offSet, MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK);
                    } else {
                        cache = cipher.doFinal(buffer, offSet, inputLen - offSet);
                    }
                    out.write(cache, 0, cache.length);
                    i++;
                    offSet = i * MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK;
                }

                byte[] decryptedData = out.toByteArray();
                out.close();

                return new String(decryptedData, "UTF-8");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("decryptByPublicKey - Exception: ", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    It shows BadPaddingException.
    javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2223)
```

Since, I have tried to reverse the method (encrypt by public key and decrypt by private key), it is okay.

Do anyone can tell me what's the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

From the error given 
**It shows BadPaddingException.javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error**

Please check the size of your buffer on (int inputLen = buffer.length). You need to pad out the data to be the required block size.

Comment: data string is a json string, just say the the length of buffer byte array will be same as the json character length. Since the MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK is set to 128 length. So I think the while..loop will control the length 
cache = cipher.doFinal(buffer, offSet, MAX_DECRYPT_BLOCK) 
to 
cache = cipher.doFinal(buffer, 0, 128);

So I don't know what wrong is it.

Comment: The encryption code is from other people, so I cant share it out

Comment: from this code it is hard to tell the exact problem, why you pass decoded keybytes here "X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);". It should be encoded Key

Comment: I want to do the Digital Signing decrypt by X509EncodedKeySpec

Answer (score 0):

You should only call `doFinal()` once, the last time. Every other time you should be calling `update()`.

But it doesn't make sense to do this. Encrypting with a private key isn't encryption, it is digital signing.

Comment: Yes, I am doing a digital signing for the both parties

Comment: But as the same things, it is working in public key using for encryption and private for decryption before.

Comment: But the error I mentioned in my answer remains. I'm not sure you even need the loop: one `Cipher.doFinal()` on the entire ciphertext array should be sufficent. It should work out the RSA block-size requirements internally.